Different definitions of vector rotation by quaternion.
I was implementing the rotation of a 3D vector by a quaternion, implementing the formula that I've found in this thread.
To testing my function, I've rotated some vectors by using matlab, in particular the quatrotate function, so I were able to write tests by using the Matlab results.
All the test that I've made failed. After checking it a bit, I've noticed that in the thread the definition of vector rotation was performed by following formula in the original thread:
$$p' = q \times p \times q*$$
where
$$p = (v_x, v_y, v_z, 0) \Leftrightarrow p = (v, 0)$$
Instead, in the matlab help page, the definition is different:

If I write the matlab definition formula in my code, all tests pass, so at least my quaternion class is correct (I've performed a lot of other tests about multiplications, conjugate etc and all of them seems correct).
So I'd like to know what's the differences between the formulas, and which one should I pick in order to correctly rotate the vector.

Formulas and when they are true

$p' = q \cdot p \cdot q^{-1}$ is always correct. This uses the most common rotation convention also called passive rotation.

$p' = q \cdot p \cdot q^{\ast}$ is only correct for unit quaternions $q$ ($\left| q \right| = 1$), because $q^{\ast} = \frac{q^{\ast}}{\left| q \right|^{2}} = \frac{q^{\ast}}{q \cdot q^{\ast}} = \frac{1}{q} = q^{-1}$ (which gives you the formula above). This also uses passive rotation. You may also see $p' = q \cdot p \cdot \overline{q}$ which is the same.

$p' = q^{-1} \otimes \left[ \frac{0}{p} \right] \otimes q = q^{-1} \cdot p \cdot q$ is always correct (active rotation) (it uses a different notation because it treats quaternions as vectors to work with them, so it's $p' = q^{-1} \cdot p \cdot q$) but it uses another convention for rotations then $p' = q \cdot p \cdot q^{-1}$, rotating in the opposite direction (this is called active rotation). You can see that by left-multiplying $q$ and right-multiplying $q^{-1}$ which gives you $q \cdot p' \cdot q^{-1} = p$ aka it reverses the first rotation via a rotation by the same angle aka a rotation in the opposite direction. See more about this here.

$p' = q^{\ast} \cdot p \cdot q$ is only correct for unit quaternions (active rotation) for the same reason as $p' = q \cdot p \cdot q^{\ast}$.



Remark
$\Re\left( p \right) = 0$ has to be true for all these formulas because if $p = v_{x} \cdot i + v_{y} \cdot j + v_{z} \cdot k$ is the quaternion describing the point you want to rotate around the origin: $p \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} v_{x}\\ v_{y}\\ v_{z}\\ \end{pmatrix}$. "$p = \left( v_{x},\, v_{y},\, v_z,\, 0 \right) \Leftrightarrow p = \left( v,\, 0 \right)$" would be the quaternion $p$, so that just states the trivial contdition $\Re\left( p \right) = 0$.

Links / References
Wikipedia states $p' = q \cdot p \cdot q^{\ast}$ in it's article about rotation via quaternons, gives an example calculation for this and gives more relations.
This article talks about some rotation formulas including $p' = q \cdot p \cdot q^{-1}$ and $q' = q^{-1} \cdot p \cdot q$ and states some properties for quaternions (I used some of them my answer).
For more informations on what active and passive rotations are you can read the Wikipedia article about this.

Thanks a lot, this clarifies a lot of things for me.
